# Tinymce dynamically generated icon list

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, document

i'm trying to create dynamically generated icon list for tiny mce. I have written all related php functions i call the function through following code.

```
$.post(url_file, { 
       content_name: $class_name, 
       page_url: filePath,
       app_code: app_code
   },
   function(data){
       var buttonlist = data;
   });
```

i need to pass above 3 parameters in order to get these icons . Now i have `buttonlist` . I tried `document.write(buttonlist)` but it gives me `missing : after property id` error.
i am trying to print this within ;

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "elm1", 
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "Archiv,pagebreak,safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,
                   style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,
                   emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,
                   media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,
                   directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,
                   xhtmlxtras,template",
    --> document.write(buttonlist);
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
```

Do you have an idea how i can print this value inside tinymce code?
Help much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the buttons dynamically right?

try this:

for getting it, use json for each button line:

```
$.post(url_file, { 
   content_name: $class_name, 
   page_url: filePath,
   app_code: app_code
},
function(data){
   var buttons = $.parseJSON(data)
   var buttonlist1 = buttons.line1;
   var buttonlist2 = buttons.line2;
   var buttonlist3 = buttons.line3;
});
```

and then for MCE initialization:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "elm1", 
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "Archiv,pagebreak,safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,
               style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,
               emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,
               media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,
               directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,
               xhtmlxtras,template",
--> theme_advanced_buttons1 : buttonlist1,
--> theme_advanced_buttons2 : buttonlist2,
--> theme_advanced_buttons3 : buttonlist3,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. i tried it. but then tinymce is not loading there must be something wrong. But i don't see anything wrong with json data. when i `alert(buttonlist2);` it alerts correct icons.

Comment: ahha hah! it worked! i put `tinyMCE.init()` inside `function(data){` thanks duuuuuuude !

Answer (score 0):

When creating a page using php the php code gets executed first before the page gets delievered to the client. Therefor you may do something like:

```
<?php
    $my_generated_buttonlist = '"bold, italic, underline"';
?>

tinyMCE.init({

    mode : "exact",

    elements : "elm1", 

    theme : "advanced",

    plugins : "Archiv,pagebreak,safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    theme_advanced_buttons1: '<?php echo $my_generated_buttonlist; ?>',

    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    ...
```

Comment: I cannot get my values into a php variable, that's why i'm stuck with this. im getting these icons from the database so i have to query it, my php function generates these icon list after querying it. But to query it , i need to pass the variables i have passed to $.post.

Comment: ok say i solved this, i had only one solution i wrote the content into a file and echo file contents. but i have another issue. I have few different textareas in a file and i want to show different icons on each tinymce instance. when i used my solution it always loads the 1st one it loads. obvious.. have any idea for any solution for this?